# How can I find out the proxy address I am behind?

Tags: proxy

I am behind a proxy, but I don't  know the URL/port.  Is there a way to find this out? 
Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean the IP/port you use to connect to your proxy or the IP you are expose to the internet with?

Answer (score 5):

you can find your proxy in two ways. Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then

**Method 1:**

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

Description: It will search **proxy** string in the `env` command which lists all system environmental variables.

**Method 2:**

```
cat /etc/environment
```

Answer (score 1):

visit http://www.whatismyip.com/

it will show your IP address. If you are behind a proxy it will show the address of proxy

Comment: doesn't work for me .. i'm behind a proxy but it says "no proxy detected"